# JSF Composite Component target actions fail within the c:forEach Tag

Tags: jsf, jstl, el, composite-component, mojarra

We use `commandButtons` inside a `c:forEach` tag, where the button's `action` receives the `forEach` `var` attribute as a parameter like this:

```
<c:forEach var="myItem" items="#{myModel}">
    <h:commandButton
        action="#{myController.process(myItem)}"
        value="#{myItem.name}" />
</c:forEach>
```

This works just fine. If we wrap the `commandButton` in a composite component, it does not work anymore, though: The controller gets called, but parameter is always `null`. 
Here is an example of a `c:forEach` Tag containing a button and composite component wrapping a button. The first one works, the second one does not.

```
<c:forEach var="myItem" items="#{myModel}">
    <h:commandButton
        action="#{myController.process(myItem)}"
        value="#{myItem.name}" />
    <my:mybutton
        action="#{myController.process(myItem)}" 
        value="#{myItem.name}" /> 
</c:forEach>
```

with the following `my:mybutton` implementation:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="action" required="true" targets="button" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="true" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:commandButton id="button"
        value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
    </h:commandButton>
</composite:implementation>
```

Please Note, that the button's `value` attribute, which is also bound to the `c:ForEach` `var`, works just fine. It is only the `action`, propagated through the composite component's `targets` mechanism, that does not get evaluated correctly.
Can anoymone please explain, why this happens and how to fix this?

*We are on mojarra 2.2.8, el-api 2.2.5, tomcat 8.0.*

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with Mojarra 2.2.14 and Tomcat 8.5.16. I only didn't manually include EL in the project as Tomcat has its own EL version already.

Comment: I reproduced your problem when the given c:forEach snippet is in turn enclosed in another composite component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in Mojarra or perhaps an oversight in the JSF specification with regard to retargeting method expressions for composite components.

The work around is the below `ViewDeclarationLanguage`.

```
public class FaceletViewHandlingStrategyPatch extends ViewDeclarationLanguageFactory {

    private ViewDeclarationLanguageFactory wrapped;

    public FaceletViewHandlingStrategyPatch(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactory wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewDeclarationLanguage getViewDeclarationLanguage(String viewId) {
        return new FaceletViewHandlingStrategyWithRetargetMethodExpressionsPatch(getWrapped().getViewDeclarationLanguage(viewId));
    }

    @Override
    public ViewDeclarationLanguageFactory getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    private class FaceletViewHandlingStrategyWithRetargetMethodExpressionsPatch extends ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper {

        private ViewDeclarationLanguage wrapped;

        public FaceletViewHandlingStrategyWithRetargetMethodExpressionsPatch(ViewDeclarationLanguage wrapped) {
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
        }

        @Override
        public void retargetMethodExpressions(FacesContext context, UIComponent topLevelComponent) {
            super.retargetMethodExpressions(new FacesContextWithFaceletContextAsELContext(context), topLevelComponent);
        }

        @Override
        public ViewDeclarationLanguage getWrapped() {
            return wrapped;
        }
    }

    private class FacesContextWithFaceletContextAsELContext extends FacesContextWrapper {

        private FacesContext wrapped;

        public FacesContextWithFaceletContextAsELContext(FacesContext wrapped) {
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
        }

        @Override
        public ELContext getELContext() {
            boolean isViewBuildTime  = TRUE.equals(getWrapped().getAttributes().get(IS_BUILDING_INITIAL_STATE));
            FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) getWrapped().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
            return (isViewBuildTime && faceletContext != null) ? faceletContext : super.getELContext();
        }

        @Override
        public FacesContext getWrapped() {
            return wrapped;
        }
    }
}
```

Install it as below in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<factory>
    <view-declaration-language-factory>com.example.FaceletViewHandlingStrategyPatch</view-declaration-language-factory>
</factory>
```

---

How I nailed down it?

We have confirmed that the problem is that the method expression argument became `null` when the action is invoked in a composite component while the action itself is declared in another composite component.

```
<h:form>
    <my:forEachComposite items="#{['one', 'two', 'three']}" />
</h:form>
```

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="items" required="true" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.items}" var="item">
        <h:commandButton id="regularButton" value="regular button" action="#{bean.action(item)}" />
        <my:buttonComposite value="cc button" action="#{bean.action(item)}" />
    </c:forEach>
</cc:implementation>
```

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="action" required="true" targets="compositeButton" />
    <cc:actionSource name=""></cc:actionSource>
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:commandButton id="compositeButton" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
</cc:implementation>
```

First thing I did was locating the code who's responsible for creating the [`MethodExpression`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/MethodExpression.html) instance behind `#{bean.action(item)}`. I know it's normally created via [`ExpressionFactory#createMethodExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.html#createMethodExpression-javax.el.ELContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class:A-). I also know that all EL context variables are normally provided via [`ELContext#getVariableMapper()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELContext.html#getVariableMapper--). So I placed a debug breakpoint in `createMethodExpression()`.

[image]
​
In the call stack we can inspect the `ELContext#getVariableMapper()` and also who's responsible for creating the `MethodExpression`. In a test page with a composite component in turn nesting one regular command button and one composite command button we can see the following difference in `ELContext`:

Regular button:
​
[image]

We can see that the regular button uses `DefaultFaceletContext` as `ELContext` and that the `VariableMapper` contains the right `item` variable.

Composite button:

[image]
​​
We can see that the composite button uses standard `ELContextImpl` as `ELContext` and that the `VariableMapper` doesn't contain the right `item` variable. So we need to go some steps back in the call stack to see where this standard `ELContextImpl` is coming from and why it's being used instead of `DefaultFaceletContext`.

[image]

Once found where the particular `ELContext` implementation is created, we can find that it's obtained from `FacesContext#getElContext()`. But this does not represent the EL context of the composite component! This is represented by the current `FaceletContext`. So we need to go some more steps back to figure out why the `FaceletContext` isn't being passed down.

[image]

We can see here that `CompositeComponentTagHandler#applyNextHander()` doesn't pass through the `FaceletContext` but the `FacesContext` instead. This is the exact part which might have been an oversight in the JSF specification. The `ViewDeclarationLanguage#retargetMethodExpressions()` should have asked for another argument, representing the actual `ELContext` involved.

But it is what it is. We can't change the spec on the fly right now. Best what we can do is to report an issue to them.

The above shown `FaceletViewHandlingStrategyPatch` works as follows by ultimately overriding the `FacesContext#getELContext()` as below:

```
@Override
public ELContext getELContext() {
    boolean isViewBuildTime  = TRUE.equals(getWrapped().getAttributes().get(IS_BUILDING_INITIAL_STATE));
    FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) getWrapped().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
    return (isViewBuildTime && faceletContext != null) ? faceletContext : super.getELContext();
}
```

You see, it checks if JSF is currently building the view and if there's a `FaceletContext` present. If so, then return the `FaceletContext` instead of the standard `ELContext` implementation (note that [`FaceletContext` just extends `ELContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletContext.html)). This way the `MethodExpression` will be created with the right `ELContext` holding the right `VariableMapper`.

Comment: The situation is not quite the same as in our case: We did not use the `<c:forEach>` in a composite component, but in a facelet, that is embedded in a view using `<ui:include>`. This it not quite the same as in your setup, but the problem seems to have the same root cause. I could also see an empty ELContext in `ExpressionFactory#createMethodExpression()` and your fix works for us, too.